# Return the shortest string

Tags: c++, string, string-length

I'm trying to write a function that will return the shortest string from a `vector<string>`:

```
// Find the shortest string.
string shortestString(vector<string> v) {
    string shortest;
    int shortss = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (string s : v) {
            if (i = 0) {
            shortss = s.length();
            shortest = s;
            i++;
        }
        else if (s.length() < shortss) {
            shortss = s.length();
            shortest = s;
        }
    }
    return shortest;
}
```

IDK if I have made some stupid mistake, but it returns nothing.
Here is my `main()`:

```
int main() {
    vector<string> words = { "a", "ab", "abc" };
    string shor = shortestString(words);
    cout << shor;
}
```

Nothing is printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you initialize `shortss` to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, you don't need to check for "first" iteration. In other words, any string you have is going to be shorter that max int.

Comment: OMG i didnt see i == 0 error.

Comment: Pass your vector by const reference otherwise you are making an unnecessary copy of it. If you want to be super clever, you could return a reference to the shortest string from the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement:

```
        if (i = 0) {
```

should be

```
        if (i == 0) {
```

With the single equals `=`, it's an *assignment* statement and the result is the value that is assigned. So it wouldn't be testing `i` to see whether it is zero or not, it would be assigning 0 to `i` and then not running that `if` block.

Comment: Even though i is only incremented to 1 it'll still loop through all the strings in the vector since a range based loop is used, not accesses based on indices

Comment: @illeyezur: Good point thanks, I've removed that incorrect bit.

Comment: I'll add that `if (i = 0)` is a valid test (as well as being an assignment), but its result is `FALSE` instead of `TRUE`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use an STL algorithm to do this.

```
smin = *std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                     [] (const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) { 
                         return s1.length() < s2.length(); }
                     );
```